# Excluding people from an effect

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I own a Minecraft factions realm in pocket edition and want to make it so players cant grief people’s bases. I have already set up a repeat command block that goes like:

```
effect @a[r=20] mining_fatigue 1 225
```

But players also want it so that they can destroy blocks in their base as well. How do I exclude people from this mining fatigue effect?

Answer (score 3):

First, add a tag to the teams' players:

`tag player add tag`

Then, target other players within the enemies' base:

`effect @a[tag=!tag,dx=10,dy=10,dz=10,x=0,y=0,z=0] minecraft:mining_fatigue 1 225`
Should theoretically work

*(the values 10 and 0 in the dx, dy, dz, x, y and z values are example coords of the enemies' base corner coordinates)*

Comment: It says, “No targets matched selector”. I’m on bedrock edition by the way.

Comment: hmm.. actually, I did more research and found out that dx, dy and dz are not opposite corner coords, rather the distance to the opposite corner coordinates. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: HalpMe I'm pretty sure you can't do tags like that in bedrock

Comment: Selectors like dx, dy, dz, x, y, and z are in bedrock edition. I made a sketch for you if you need more explanation on the selectors I mentioned earlier.
  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ln4.jpg